# What does a rotating universe look like?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

If everything in the universe were revolving around an axis, how would that affect space-time? In my mind it would be no different from a normal universe since it would look normal in a comoving frame, but I want to get an insight from someone more knowledgeable on the subject.

Comment: The reason and details why it was rotating around an axis would be rather important.

Answer (score 1):

This is a much-studied question, and quite a subtle one. There are two things to take into consideration: (1) our most accurate and detailed knowledge of spacetime and its relation to matter---that is, general relativity; (2) is the proposed state of rotation even possible?

The answer to (2) is related to issues about whether the universe is finite in spatial extent. That is not known. But for the sake of argument let's take it to be finite. It would still be vast, just not infinite. In this case one can propose and discuss a state of overall rotation. It is a well-defined idea. For an infinite universe you could still propose some huge part of it to be in a state of overall rotation.

We can now bring in (1): general relativity. General relativity says that this state of rotation has observable effects and thus can be distinguished from a state of no rotation. To be precise, the motion of all the matter will have an effect on the nature of spacetime at any one place. It is a small effect but it could be observed through the behaviour of light sent traveling around a large loop, and by precession of gyroscopes. In technical language, we say that there are curvature-related effects, and the particular type of curvature is sensitive to the kind of overall rotation we are considering.

If you are sitting on a disc which has been made to rotate in synchrony with the universal rotation then you be able to observe a centrifugal force.

Comment: Would it be impossible for an infinite universe to be rotating, and for the rotaion to be detectable using only intrinsic properties?

Comment: @D.Halsey Sorry, but I don't know much about the idea of "an infinite universe". I read the words but I struggle to see whether they are meaningful. I can understand infinity in a mathematical context, or as a way of talking about an inverse of zero, but does the concept apply to space and its fields? I do not know. So I can't help you about a rotating infinite universe except to show you this sense of caution about the very concept.

Comment: I'm not an authority on the subject either, but I find it easier to envision "an infinite universe" than one that is finite but unbounded, especially when combined with the philosophical viewpoint that the universe is not an actual physical object, but rather just the set of all its contents. (Sorry for the digression, though.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an exact GR solution of a rotating universe calculated by [Godel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_metric).

In the end of the wikipedia article there some comments about this kind of models.

The description of the metric and its geometric features is  beyond my basic GR understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I confess that I do not understand the Godel model as described in the Wikipedia article.

However, the finite model I do understand is homogeneous at very large scales, which is a reasonably good model matching what is observable in the observable universe. It can be conceptualized as a 3D hyper-surface of a 4D hyper-sphere. If such a universe was spinning on a axis, the axis would have to be a connection in the 4D space between a point and its antipode. Rotational spinning (in 4D space) about this axis would cause different (in principle) conditions in different regions based on distance from the antipodes.  This would be a contradiction to homogeneity.

The homogeneous infinite flat model also has a problem with rotation. In this model there are property differences related to distance from the axis.

I am not sure, but I think it is very plausible that these non-homogeneous differences would show up in observation of the CMB radiation in both the finite and infinite models.